# Mocked restTemplate.postForObject is not being used in execution of test

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

I have mocked a postForObject resttemplate call using mickito.

***Mockito.when(restTemplate.postForObject(Mockito.eq(remoteServerlocation), Mockito.any(Input.class), Mockito.eq(String.class))).thenReturn(responseString);***

But in the actual code, this mocked value is not being used and trying to call the remote location.

***String responseString = restTemplate.postForObject(url, input, String.class);***

As per my understanding , I have mocked exactly same call. But not working. 
Any help on this will be thankful.

I'm autowiring the class which contains the testing method in testcase class. And this test class I have created restTemplate using new.

TestClass

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
public class ActionImplTest {

    @Autowired
    private ActionImpl recommendation;

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    @Test
    public void performActionTest() throws Exception {
        String textInput = "InputText";
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        map.put("convId", "C123");
        map.put("reID", 1);
        map.put("chID", "Chann_1");

        String convID = "1254356671563";
        String chId = "2";
        String responseString = "Success"
        Mockito.when(restTemplate.postForObject(Mockito.eq("remoteServerlocation"), Mockito.any(Input.class), Mockito.eq(String.class))).thenReturn(responseString);

        Map<String, Object> response = recommendation.performAction(textInput, map, convID, chId);  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a `verify` step at the end of your test, mockito will give you some hints on what was expected and what actually has been called:

```
Mockito.verify(restTemplate).postForObject(
    Mockito.eq(remoteServerlocation), Mockito.any(Input.class), Mockito.eq(String.class));
```

Comment: I have done this. But still not getting any clue from the error report on this. Error is saying connection time out on the remote url

Comment: Have you created a mock or a spy for the `RestTemplate`? Could you provide your complete test code?

Comment: Error is saying connection time out on the remote url  --- it's call to real RestTemplate . you didn't create mock/stub . Do you create restTemplate with mock(restTemplate) ? Looks like it's autowired - real field

Comment: RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(); you create real object. use RestTemplate restTemplate = mock(RestTemplate.class)

Comment: Well, you have to create either a mock or a spy, and inject that in your code under test, so it will use it. Have a look at https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-mocking-beans

Comment: If you are using an older version of spring where mockbeans are not available, have a look at http://www.baeldung.com/injecting-mocks-in-spring

Comment: I have mocked the restTemplate. Still no progress. After a long search got to know that in the code , I was not able to autowire Rest template. So I have created it using new . I hope if the mocked url needs to be specified using the same resttemplate object. ie, I mock a resttemplate in testcase and using another restTemplate(created using new) in the actual code. Is this correct? If it is, how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of what I meant in the comment referring to the [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-mocking-beans).

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class ActionImplTest {

    @MockBean
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private ActionImpl recommendation;
```